# The technological limitation of information extraction from a drop of blood

Tags: blood-tests, technology

In light of the sentencing of Elizabeth Holmes just now, I would like to ask if there is a technological limitation for extracting the full spectrum of test information from a drop of blood. [This Quora answer](https://qr.ae/pvdkWx) says "Not with current technology. The laws of physics and chemistry don’t allow for doing 150–200 tests on a 25uL blood sample." I suppose this is a bit exaggeration to attribute the difficulty if not the impossibility to physics or chemistry, but rather a rhetorical emphasis on the limitation of the current engineering and medical methodology. I would like to hear a detailed support or refutation of my aforementioned hunch.

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please edit your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I just edited my question.

Comment: 25μL is small and so I checked the size and found that a drop of blood is [actually roughly 35μL](https://www.bu.edu/globalhealthtechnologies/2016/03/21/not-every-drop-of-blood-is-identical/).  Is the answer from Quora really scientifically sound when there are no citations and fundamental details are not accurate? When researching, you need to look at the validity of what is put forward as evidence of the so-called answer, and this discrepancy would in my mind bring the answer into question.

Comment: @ChrisRogers: That is precisely why I bring the question here instead of accepting what is in Quora for an answer.

Comment: Hard to prove a negative at the cutting edge of technology. It would all depend on exactly what tests you are doing. You can extract DNA from a single cell and sequence it, especially through procedures that involve amplification steps, and it is certainly not beyond possibility that there would be 200 individual, DNA carrying, cells in a drop of blood - no DNA in a RBC in humans.

Comment: @bob1 with ~5k WBC per ul, there should be more than enough DNA for modern sequencing equipment. Meaning you could probably get full sequencing and transcriptomics out of it. The limit for mass spectrometry is apparently ~50fmol, so I presume we could get data on the most abundant proteins as well. Of course, the question is at what cost...

Comment: All well and good, but most common blood tests don't look at genetics. They measure electrolytes, lipids, cell counts, and so forth -- tests that take more volume than a drop of blood with current technologies. That's why Ms. Holmes is going to prison for 11 years. She sold investors on the idea it could be done with a single drop.

Comment: @CareyGregory I totally agree, not those sorts of tests in those sorts of volumes. I'm merely surprised she managed to fool so many people (including scientists) for so long. I guess a good scam works well...

Comment: @CareyGregory I‘m positive that you can do a better guesstimate than current lab results (which are generally reported with a +/-10% cell count) by doing scRNA-Seq of a few ul of blood, that gives you the immune cell population and even further characteristics [which type, and subtype of T-cells], lipids and proteins you would get with mass spec and electrolytes the blood gas analyser already work with very little blood. But this is absolutely cutting edge technology which costs thousands of pounds…

Comment: I‘m positive that the promises of Mrs. Holmes (or at least a few) *could* be done with a single drop of blood, but only once and then they would have to file for bankruptcy…